# Is this the right way of implementing undirected graph using adjacency list?

Tags: c++, arrays, list, graph

First of all ,I am new to graphs.After researching through the concepts of graphs.I thought of implementing in c++. When I searched for implementation i felt it very hard to understand the codes ,So i thought of implementing myself.

Following is the code i tried:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Node {
    int data;
    Node *link;

};

//creating array of nodes
struct Node *array[10];
//creating array of head pointers to point each of the array node.
struct Node *head[10];
//creating array of current pointers to track the list on each array node.
struct Node *cur[10];

void create(int v)
{

    for (int i = 0; i < v; i++) {
        array[i] = new Node;
        head[i] = cur[i] = array[i];
        array[i]->data = i;
        array[i]->link = NULL;
    }

}

void add(int fr, int to)
{
    Node *np = new Node;
    np->data = to;
    np->link = NULL;

    if (head[fr]->link == NULL) {
        head[fr]->link = np;
        cur[fr] = np;

    } else {
        cur[fr]->link = np;
        cur[fr] = np;
    }

    /*Node* np1=new Node;
    np1->data=fr;
    np1->link=NULL;
    if(head[to]->link==NULL)
    {
    head[to]->link=np1;
    cur[to]=np1;
    }else
    {
    cur[to]->link=np1;
    cur[to]=np1;
    }*/

}

void print(int a)
{
    Node *p = NULL;
    p = head[a];

    for (; p != NULL; p = p->link)
    { cout << p->data; }

}



main()
{

    int a;
    cout << "enter the size of array";
    cin >> a;
    create(a);
    //adding edges
    add(1, 4);
    add(1, 3);
    add(0, 3);
    add(0, 2);
    print(0);
    cout << "\n";
    print(1);
    //print(3);

}
```

Explanation:

1) Asking the user to enter an integer(no.of vertices),accordingly i am creating an array with requested size.At the same time i am pointing the head and cur pointers to each of the array node. The index number of the array is equal to vertex number.

2)adding edges from one vertex to other by add function. if the head node of a vertex from which an edge emanates is null then i point the head=cur=new node(np),else i am updating cur pointer after each addition. Head will be pointing to the array index node.
3)Printing the edges connected to the requested node.

My questions are:

1)Is this way of implementation right?

2)In the above case lets assume we are connecting vertex 1 and vertex 3.with the above code3 is linked to 1.I wanted to automatically update connection from vertex 3 to vertex 1,So i added the code which is inside the comment section in add function.When i tried running the code it asked me to enter size of array ,i enter some integer it shows me segmentation fault. why?

Comment: can you tell me what value of integer you have given as input.

Comment: i tried giving 3 and 4 as 'a', both of them gave segmentation fault.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll try to give you the idea.

In an undirected graph every node can be connected to any other node.
This means a node 'points' to any number of other nodes.
In you code instead each node has `Node*link;` which is a pointer to the next node. You need a list (or an array) of links instead: each node must contain a link to all the node it is connected to. This is the adjacency list. Something like

```
struct Node
{
    int data;
    ADJ* adjs; // list of Node*
};

struct ADJ
{
    ADJ* next;
    Node* data;
};
```

Here adjs is the list of adjacency.

Also your solution for `void print(int a)` is more similar to what you would find in a common list. You need to print all the adjacency of a node, i.e. all the node it points to.

Remember that since the graph is undirected you need both the pointert A->B and B->A

Comment: So you mean to say first we create an array of ADJ and make the *next pointer of ADJ to point Node's node one after the other.

Comment: Exactly, this is the representation with adjacency lists. As a bonus, you can also implement directed graph with the same structure. You can have some variations, for example instead of a list of Node* you can have an array of Node*, but the concept is the same.

Answer (score 0):

After calling create(3) your array looks something like below:

```
array  
0 -> (0,NULL)
1 -> (1,NULL)
2 -> (2,NULL)
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

Segmentation fault occured when add(1,4) is called.

In the first part i.e.

```
Node *np = new Node;
np->data = to;
np->link = NULL;

if (head[fr]->link == NULL) {
    head[fr]->link = np;
    cur[fr] = np;

} else {
    cur[fr]->link = np;
    cur[fr] = np;
}
```

no problem at all.

Now array looks as shown:

```
array  
0 -> (0,NULL)
1 -> (1,->) (4,NULL)
2 -> (2,NULL)
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

But the Next part is the cause of segmentation fault i.e.

```
Node* np1=new Node;
np1->data=fr;
np1->link=NULL;
if(head[to]->link==NULL)
{
head[to]->link=np1;
cur[to]=np1;
}else
{
cur[to]->link=np1;
cur[to]=np1;
}
```

problem is in this line:

```
head[to]->link==NULL
```

Here value of to is 4 it means your code trying access link part of head[4] but head[4] is not storing address of valid Node.

Comment: i think its head[4] instead of head[2]. And i tried giving 'a' as 5,it works fine.Thank you so much.